# using a shortcode in a hyperlink

Tags: php, plugin-development, shortcode

I am trying to use a shortcode inside of a hyperlink

```
<a class="wpb_button_a" title="Reserve Now" href="/reservation/?unitrate=[print_csv position="5"]&amp;unitsize=5%20X%205&amp;moveinoffer=[print_csv position="8"]"><span class="wpb_button  wpb_btn-warning wpb_btn-large tocenter">Reserve Now</span></a>
```

when i use that code above and publish the page it changes to

```
<a class="wpb_button_a" title="Reserve Now" href="/reservation/?unitrate=[print_csv position="><span class="wpb_button wpb_btn-warning wpb_btn-large tocenter">Reserve Now</span></a>
```

those shortcodes are just regular text nothing big, the outcome for me should be

```
<a class="wpb_button_a" title="Reserve Now" href="/reservation/?unitrate=60&amp;unitsize=5%20X%205&amp;moveinoffer=N/A"><span class="wpb_button  wpb_btn-warning wpb_btn-large tocenter">Reserve Now</span></a>
```

any help is appreciated in advanced

Update:  Here is my overall code for the shortcode

```
function _load_google_csv( $atts ) {

    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'position' => '',
    ), $atts ) );

    ob_start();

    // store spreadsheet content into variable
    $data = file_get_contents('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oC88LWXn4SgvVzK3wQAojXk7UM5tDjuWuMZDAjQTGjw/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv');

    // Convert Comma separted String to Array
    $data = explode(',', $data );


    // Remove Comment to know the array position of the value you want to pull
    #echo '<pre>', print_r( $data, 1), '</pre>';

    /* The first two array value are like this,  
    [0] => 5X5
[1] => Only 1 Left
5X10

    You see the second array value is "Only 1 Left (Newline) 5X10" and since you don't
     want to pull 5X10, this can be remove from the string using str_replace function, 
     refer to http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_replace.asp, you may also want
      to improve your CSV format to avoid using of str_replace

    Doing it step by step

    #get the second array value
    $array_1 = $data[1] // Value of $array_1 is "Only 1 Left (Newline) 5X10"

    # Remove "5X10" from $array_1 value using str_replace();
    $desired_value = str_replace('5X10', '', $array_1); 

    echo $desired_value; // $desired_value Will now output a value of "Only 1 Left"

    */

    echo '', print_r( str_replace('5X10', '', $data[$position]), 1), '';
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('print_csv','_load_google_csv');
```

what this does is load a csv from google sheets that has all the data.

the 2 most important pieces of information that gets transferred to the next page that stays in the url is the price, unit size and offer.

those pieces stay in the url and are pulled into the page using

```
echo $_GET['unitrate'];
```

by doing this the client can simply make changes using google sheets to update the information when needed.

Comment: you can't do that, and it is a very poor idea even if you could.

Comment: would there be another solution??

Comment: solution for what? you should just not do it

Comment: ok, so what your telling me that what i need to get done there is no way possible of doing it.

Comment: Everything properly coded should be a beter idea. Anyways, without knowing your setup and what your shortcode is suppose to do, and what exactly you are after, your question is useless

Comment: ill edit my post and inform you

Comment: You could make the entire link a shortcode and turn the `position` into an attribute of shortcode.

Comment: @PieterGoosen Updated post

Comment: @Howdy_McGee, Updated Post

Comment: can anyone help?

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/ will evaluate the shortcode, but you might as well call a function directly. Also, by doing things this way your page will be pretty slow having to wait for content from an external source on every request. It would be better to handle this all from the JavaScript side of things.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use double quotes (") inside the shortcode, since you are using double quotes to specify the href attribute. The browser thinks your href text ends at `position=`. 
Use single quotes instead: `href="/reservation/?unitrate=[print_csv position='5']&amp;...`
I agree with the comments that there is a better way to do this, but I provide a potential answer anyway so you can avoid this in the future.

Comment: no no no no, you should just not do such things... what happens when the plugin is turned off???? just don't do it